# Fit FrameLayout under appbar while using NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, android-appbarlayout, android-framelayout

My problem can probably be solved quite easily but I unfortunately cannot work out the trick. I have set up a `NavigationDrawer` by using the the one provided by Android Studio. My problem is that I can't fit the `FrameLayout` under the appbar without making the `NavigationDrawer` unusable. I tried several things like using a Linear Layout or trying Relative layout with `android:layout_below`. But every time I do these kinds of things switching the Fragments in the `FrameView` with the `NavigationDrawer` doesn't work anymore.

My XML-Code for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_map_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If you need any further code I will post it as fast as I can.

Every help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
`android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"`
```

Remove the above code from your content layout.